# How to appear the arrow using sap.m.Popover

Tags: sapui5

I'm using SAPUI5

I allready create de Object Sap.m.popover, and appears on bottom of the button when click, but the arrow up its not there.

What i miss?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check in developer tools if any request is getting a 404? Please post a minimal example with this issue

Answer (score 0):

There are API properties for controlling the arrow positioning (placement) and it also depends on the device / browser how the arrow is displayed.

If the examples from the explored app or from the test page run fine for you, then try to copy the code from one of these resources:

[Examples](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Popover/samples)

[Developer Test page](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/Popover.html)

If this does not help, consider opening a [new GitHub issue](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new) for OpenUI5 or an SAP ticket to analyze the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to missing of CSS. Please try to update the UI5 library. 1.28.7 version is recommended. Thanks